# Starting selenium server from java in the background

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-server

I want to make easy-to-use selenium tests - just run one file and it starts the server, connects to it, run the tests, then close the server and exit (on windows).

I don't want the user to see the selenium console so I want to hide it if possible (run it in background and maybe log output). How can I start selenium server directly from Java?

Comment: Sounds like selenium server is installed and run locally. If you use [RemoteWebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver), you can run it on antoher machine so that the user does not see any server console output.

Comment: But I need to run it locally because I want to see the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it wasn't that hard (at least on windows). I used to start selenium server like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-xxx.jar <options>
```

To start it without console I just use **javaw**:

```
javaw -jar selenium-server-xxx.jar <options>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a windows `.bat` file and run the `.bat` file to start the selenium server. You can also include your test classes and dependencies.

eg:

```
java -cp ".;.\supportlibraries\junit4.11.jar;.\supportlibraries\poi-3.8-20120326.jar;D:\downloads\Selenium 2.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [classname]
```